# Transform a pandas dataFrame column values to rows diagonal matrix

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe  df

[image: Datafame]

How do you make dataframe like this ?

[image: Target dataframe]

I have tried

```python
df_character1 = df[['Character1','Weight']]
df_character2 = df[['Character2', 'Weight']].T
result = pd.concat([df_cha1, df_cha2], axis=1)
```

Comment: what are you looking for?

Comment: simple do `pd.pivot`

Comment: `df.pivot(index='Character1',columns='Character2',values='Weight')`